# Tensorflow: matrix multiplication on 2 GPUs in parallel

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

The below code works fine on 1 gpu.

```
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
```

However, I would like to do the matrix multiplication in parallel on separate GPUs. I have tried the below code. Unfortunately, it gives me an OOM error.

```
with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
    temp1 = tf.matmul(a[0:2,:], b[0:2,:])

with tf.device("/device:GPU:1"):
    temp2 = tf.matmul(a[2:5,:], b[2:5,:])

c = tf.concat([temp1, temp2], axis=0)
```

How would I matrix multiply in parallel?